# Cucumber: Factory Girl doesn't modify database -- creates object with .create but database table is still empty afterwards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, factory-bot

```
  p = Factory(:model) 

  ap Model.find(:all)  #output to prove that it's getting created
```

so... the print shows that the IDs of the objects is going up.... but the database remains empty as I continually refresh the view on MySQL workbench -- so my cucumber tests fail, because the controllers pull stuff from the database... but there is nothing in the database! =(

My Gem file: test

```
group :test do
    gem "cucumber", "~>0.10.3"
    gem "cucumber-rails", "0.3.2"
    gem "launchy"
    gem "hpricot"
    gem "gherkin", "~>2.4.0"

    gem "capybara", "0.4.1.2"
    gem "rspec", "1.3.2"
    gem "rspec-rails", "1.3.2"
    gem "rspec-core"
    gem "rspec-expectations"

    gem "webrat", "0.7.0"
    gem "database_cleaner"

    gem "factory_girl", "1.2.4"
    gem "shoulda", :require => nil
    gem "shoulda-matchers", :git => "https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers"
    gem "awesome_print"
    gem "cobravsmongoose"
end
```

My Requires for env.rb (cucumber env)

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'test'
ENV["RACK_ENV"] = 'test'

BASE_DOMAIN = "myapp.dev" #using POW

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../config/environment')

require 'cucumber/formatter/unicode' # Remove this line if you don't want Cucumber Unicode support
require 'cucumber/rails/world'
require 'cucumber/rails/active_record'
require 'cucumber/web/tableish'
require 'cucumber/rails/rspec' 
require 'rake'

require 'shoulda'
require 'factory_girl'
require 'factory_girl/step_definitions'
require 'awesome_print'


require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'capybara/session'
```

And in envs/test.rb

```
Bundler.require(:test) #just in case I forgot something
```

EDIT:

Some console output
Factory(:model).errors =>

```
#<ActiveRecord::Errors:0x10c5a6498 @base=#<ModelName id: 1, name: "Ready or not", status: 0, account_id: 2, user_id: 1, created_at: "2011-09-08 15:09:05", updated_at: "2011-09-08 15:09:05", description: "Things are not as they used to be", value: #<BigDecimal:10cb2c188,'0.12345E5',9(18)>, category_id: nil, allow_downloads: true, visibility: 1, locked: nil>, @errors=#<OrderedHash {}>>
```

And looking at the console during runtime, this object is def getting in INSERT INTO command... but there is this:

```
RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (1.3ms)   ROLLBACK
```

which I feel might be what is causing the problem.... some sort of pre-emptive rollback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this then:

in env.rb

```
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'database_cleaner/cucumber'
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = nil
```

Comment: Stategy "nil" doesn't clear anything. Why do you need database cleaner then?

Answer (score 3):

in features/support/env.rb make sure that you have

```
# This will prevent the deletion of the data written in the test db until the end of the 
# cucumber feature
Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

by default this is true so it looks like nothing goes in the db.

Comment: I just added that to features/support/env.rb, right after all the require's ... and it still behaves the same =(

Answer (score 1):

I would begin by seeing if there are any validation errors when the object is being saved, ie

```
p Factory(:model).errors
```

and then, if there are none, to start watching what active record does by adding a logger to stdout:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

and using that to make sure the data is being written to the db.

Past those things, I would try updating to the 2.1 version of FactoryGirl and seeing if that makes a difference.

Comment: What are your `database_cleaner` settings, if any, for these tests? It just feels like there's a rollback happening at the end of a setup method before the tests themselves are run.

Comment: I have the database_cleaner stuff commented out. It's not even required in my env.rb Also, my hooks.rb file in support/ is empty.

Comment: I would add some logging (`ActiveRecord::Base.logger.info "test"`) to narrow down _where_ the transaction is being rolled back. Also, in the vein of Matteo's answer, adding `self.use_transactional_fixtures = false` to the method being run is worth a shot, since we're stabbing in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

In the file features/support/env.rb, you should set
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation